# 54k+ files in svn directory - how to delete

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a directory in svn with 54 000 files in it. I rearranged directory so I have now 54 folder in each below 1000 files and committed this to svn.
But I'm unable to delete 54k files from svn. With delete it took me ages but now when I try committing I'm just getting:
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly

Is there any other way to delete those files easily and fast??

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: Currently linux and I got the same svn error that on tortoise in windows:

Comment: How about taking it out of SVN Repository, delete the files and commit it again. But it will delete all your history as well. Not recommended if you want to keep the history.

Comment: Every time I see the title of this question I read it in terms of *modems* because `54+(a little bit)` kps was about the best you could reliably get out of "56k" modems on standard telephone lines (limited by the quality of the signals and switching on the telephone network).

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux use the find command in association with the XArgs command.

```
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ufind.htm
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/xargs.htm
```

Something like :

```
find . -name *.foo -print | xargs rm
```

will do the trick.

Look at the 2 links I've provided for more info,  -name allows you to use normal wildcards such as * & ? , -regex allows you more control using a full regex string.

for testing, you'll want to make sure you use something like:

```
find . -name *.foo -print | xargs echo
```

so you don't accidentually delete until you know what your file list will be.

Under windows it's a little more involved.

It's been my experience in the past, that you have to keep searching, deleting a few hundred, then searching again using the search box in the upper right corner of an explorer window.

I have been meaning to write my self a little tool to deal with this scenario for sometime now, just never got round to it yet.

Comment: Quite easy, using the above info will allow you to find the files matching the file pattern in the name parameter (In your case I'm guessing .svn) and then delete them, if that's what you wish to do, all from a Linux command line.  The second part after xargs can be replaced with any command, for EG: the svn move command as suggested by the other response on the question.

Comment: No. I don't need to delete .svn. I need to delete 54 000 files from directory and I'm unable to do this due to the fact it's 54k files.

Comment: and the above commands will make a list of those files (Given the proper file masks) and process them as required, thus meaning you don't have to do each one by hand a single file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the original folder structure was in svn as well. What I would do is rollback to the original structure and create a script that would issue `[svn move][1]` for each file/directory instead. Doing it this way will preserve the commit history for the files as well, and is the preferred method for reorganizing your source tree.

You can also descend into your folder structure and commit in smaller chunks. You lose the benefit of one atomic commit that can be rolled back though. Thinking out loud, you could simulate this by branching, reorganize the branch (using svn move!) then merge the branch back to trunk -- note that you have to use svn move on the file/folders in the branch or svn won't be able to help you with the merge.

Comment: How exactly should I proceed with this?? Like:
1. moving those 54k files into a directory with svn move files toFolder.
2. move to trunk??

So now what's the proper command to move to trunk.

And secondly I really do now want to spend of this another two days.